# What's name of this article rotating feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I developed article rotator where 5 articles with images rotate automatically and user can focus one (and stop rotating) by mouseover. Click will open the article.

The article rotator is here: http://antizena.df.sk/ and it is just devel version.

**How to name it? What is the best name for this feature?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it anything you want. But it fits into the category of carousels or images sliders. [Here is a plugin](http://designm.ag/tutorials/image-rotator-css-jquery/) similar to yours called an image rotator.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it **Carousel**

Answer (score 3):

They are usually referred to as Carousels

Answer (score 1):

Article stack? Article pile? AutoSkip-Stack?

A carousel to me is something that spins and where you can see more than one element at a time. Similar to the coverflow on an iPod.